# Geoprocessing Tools not producing an output in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arcgis-10.5

I've been running a few different geoprocessing tools in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5, which seem to operate as required, the various processing windows appear to give the impression that works is going on but when I get the final tick window saying the process is complete, there is no output in the specified location.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try again but turn off background geoprocessing http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/foreground-and-background-processing.htm, it sounds like the background geoprocessor is up to its usual nefarious tricks. The processes you've run can be found in the results tab if you're setup to keep geoprocessing results https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002100000013000000

Comment: Thanks Michael. I was working remotely and it appears that internet connection / bandwidth to/from the work server may have had an influence. Everything seemed to work fine once I plugged in back in the office.

Comment: Latency is merciless. Are you trying to access data over a VPN/server connection or are you using remote desktop? I find working via remote desktop best as the data stays on the (relatively) fast intranet, exhibiting very low latency - less chance of timeout/version changed events.

Comment: It's via server connection which is notoriously variable. Pretty sure that was my issue.